# How do I cancel one certain AnyCancellable in a Set<AnyCancellable>?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, combine

I've got a `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher`, which I store in a Set of `AnyCancellable`-s. When I receive a value and after that the completion, I want this AnyCancellable to be removed from the Set.

How do I identify this certain AnyCancellable and how do I remove it? Or what is the best way to handle these cases? I checked and it doesn't automatically get removed from the bag once I receive a completion value.

```
class RandomClass {
    private var cancellableBag: Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func someMethod() {
        let request = URLRequest(...)
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .sink(...)
            .store(in: &self.cancellableBag)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4

```
class RandomClass {
    private var cancellableBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func someMethod() {
        let request = URLRequest(...)

        var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            // .. other operators here
            .sink(receiveValue: {[weak self] value in
                // ... process value here
                self?.cancellableBag.remove(cancellable!)  // << remove !!
            })
        self.cancellableBag.insert(cancellable!)     // << store !!
    }
```