# How to cancel/invalidate timer of type AnyPublisher<Date,Never> in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, publisher

I'm new in the Combine world and i have `var timer: AnyPublisher<Date,Never>` to 're-use' the timer i have in the ContentView for my SecondView, do i have to invalidate/cancel the timer when i no longer need it? If yes, how to do it?

In the previous code with a timer of type `Timer.TimerPublisher` if i had to cancel it I did it using: `timer.upstream.connect().cancel()` and now of course it keeps giving me this error: `Value of type 'AnyPublisher<Date, Never>' has no member 'upstream'`

Comment: Please have a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/replacing-foundation-timers-with-timer-publishers

Comment: If i got it right, it says that it autoconnects and autodisconnect automatically? So i don't need to cancel it @vadian

Comment: Just remove/cancel subscriber(s), with no subscription publisher is canceled automatically. Example https://stackoverflow.com/a/64421357/12299030 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/62476194/12299030 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/61540669/12299030.

Comment: Why reuse the timer? Let SecondView create its own timer.

Comment: @vacawama How to create more than one timer? I tried to do it but if i already have a timer the second one doesn't work

Comment: Just assign each timer to its own variable.

Comment: @vacawama Did it, my timers had 2 different variables but didn't work

Comment: Without source code, its hard to know where you're going wrong.  I just created a list with 20 different timers running all in the same View.  If you're still curious about this, post the code you tried in a new question, and I'm sure someone can point out your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this can help?

```
private var timerSubscription: AnyCancellable?

func setupTimer(every interval: TimeInterval, repeats: Bool, onReceive: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
    invalidateTimer()

    timerSubscription = Timer
        .publish(every: interval, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
        .sink { _ in
            onReceive()
            if !repeats {
                self.invalidateTimer()
            }
        }
}

func invalidateTimer() {
    timerSubscription?.cancel()
}
```

full service:

```
final class CombineTimerService {

// MARK: - Public Properties

var isCancelled: Bool {
    return timerSubscription == nil
}

// MARK: - Private Properties

private var timerSubscription: AnyCancellable?
private var onReceive: (() -> Void)?

// MARK: - Public

func setupTimer(every interval: TimeInterval, repeats: Bool, onReceive: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
    invalidateTimer()
    self.onReceive = onReceive

    timerSubscription = Timer
        .publish(every: interval, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
        .sink { _ in
            onReceive()
            if !repeats {
                self.invalidateTimer()
            }
        }
}

func invalidateTimer() {
    timerSubscription?.cancel()
    onReceive = nil
}

func fire() {
    onReceive?()
}
}
```

Comment: On timerSubscription = Timer.publish it says 'Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable'

Comment: I assume your'e using timer in struct. You can wrap timer in a class so you won't get such error. I sent a full class above :)